# What would be the *right* way to use netctl on a read-only root filesystem

Tags: linux, readonly, netctl

I am attempting to use a read-only root filesystem, but am having issues with netctl, since it creates and manages systemd service files as a part of its normal operation.

I have a separate partition where I keep configuration files for the software application that is run on this system, and I can always symlink the /etc/systemd/system folder out to there - but that feels like a kludgy solution.

Is there a correct way to go about this?